# Fixed or "frozen" columns in table inside Eclipse Scout

Tags: tableview, eclipse-scout, frozen-columns

I am interesting into how implement "frozen" columns inside Eclipse Scout table.

I see solution with two tables https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/99484/, but I am looking if anyone has different solution, or this is the only one.

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at what Excel describes as [freeze panes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP001217048.aspx)?

I afraid there is no support in Scout for this at the moment. You can file a change request in Bugzilla, but without any sponsoring (money or code contribution), it will be hard to implement this.

You can have a look at the approach chosen by Karsten Thoms for the RAP-UI: [Scout tables with fixed columns](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/scout-tables-with-fixed-columns/). He uses a custom field (he has extended the default RAP table).

In my opinion, if we include this feature in Scout, it should be a property on each column (frozen = true / false) and not on the table.